# How to do data argumentation with tensorflow dataset api?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use the `tf.data.dataset`  to do image argumentation while training. The code is similar to official [guideline](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) as follow:

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    lambda file, label: tuple(tf.py_func(
        _parse_train_image, [file, label],
        [tf.float32, tf.int32]
    ))
).batch(batch_size).repeat(epoch)

def _parse_train_image(file, label):
    image = cv2.imread(file.decode(), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    image = process_image(image)
    return image, label
```

The `train_data` and `train_label` here refer to two lists which contains image file paths and labels seperately. However, this transformation can only return the original image, I also need to argument the images(like flip and rotate). 
How can I continue to argument the images and return these images?

Comment: How do you implement `process_image`? This is where you should do data augmentation.

Comment: Well, I just resize and normalize the image. It is used to return the original image.

Comment: Instead, return the augmented image or apply another `map` operation on your dataset calling a function that applies data augmentation.

Comment: I tried to apply another `map` operation to rotate image, then I can only get the rotated image without the original one. It seems `map` operation acts like a chain. The code is like:
`train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_train_image).map(rotate_image).batch(batch_size).repeat(epoch)`

Comment: You should edit your original post to include what you already tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: Well, I have already made it out. The solution is to augment the images in `map` operation, like `train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_train_image).batch(batch_size).repeat(epoch)` and the `parse_train_image` can read image from disk, followed by some augmentation, which may give us a lot of images and then we can return the image list from this function.